# Factory that takes constructors

Tags: c#, interface, factory

How can I make a factory that behaves like this:

```
interface A {
}

class B: A {
 string b;
 public B(string b) { this.b = b; }
}

class Factory {
 public static T create<T>(/*somehow pass constructor parameters*/) where T: A {
  return new T(/*constructor parameters*/);
 }
}

B test = Factory.create<B>("test");
```

I know, I can just use class constructor, but this pattern may have some uses and I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: This cannot work, because the number (and types) of `/*constructor parameters*/` depend on what `T` is. Implementors of `A` are not restricted in the parameters their constructors can take. Also, a type can expose *several* constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but it ain't pretty.

```
class Factory {
    public static T Create<T>(params object[] parameters) where T : A {
        return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameters);
    }
}
```

Although this may look superficially attractive, there are problems:

- You will never know if a call works until runtime, where it can throw a nasty exception.
- Conversion of parameters can make it hard to see which constructor will get called -- if any.
- `Activator.CreateInstance` is very slow compared to `new`. You can get the constructor directly using `Type.GetConstructor()`, which is marginally faster, but it *still sucks*.

Solutions like this tend to be too clever for their own good. You are really much better off using static typing, even with factories. One alternative to a factory is accepting a `Func<T>` that will produce an instance on demand:

```
void needToUseAnAForSomething(Func<A> aCreator) {
   ...
   A a = aCreator();
}
```

And then client code can do something like this:

```
needToUseAnAForSomething(() => new B("test"));
```

In this case, of course, we could simply pass the instance directly, but in more complicated scenarios this could take the place of a factory construction.

Answer (score 0):

This can bei achieved with reflection:

```
public static T Create<T> (object[] parameters) where T : class
{
    Type[] parameterTypes = (parameters ?? Enumerable.Empty<object> ())
        .Select (parameter => parameter.GetType ()).ToArray ();
    ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor (parameterTypes);
    Debug.Assert (ctor != null);
    T instance = ctor.Invoke (parameters) as T;
    Debug.Assert (instance != null);
    return instance;
}
```

You Invoke that method by calling:

```
B test = Factory.Create<B> (new object[]{"test"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
public static object create<T>(string param) where T : A
            {
                Type type = typeof(T);
                ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
                object instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { param });

                return instance;
            }
```